# Methods for downloading files from a URL in Java

Tags: java, url, file-io, apache-commons

I want to download a binary file from a webserver which is running on a embedded device. That file can be downloaded manually after a basic http authentication by using that 
URL: `http://10.10.10.10/config.bin`... Now i want to automate this process with a simple Java application. By using the basic java tools i managed to download the file:

```
URL mlrrl = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection  con = (HttpURLConnection) mlrUrl.openConnection();

            con.setRequestMethod("GET");
            con.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
            con.setDoInput(true);
            con.setDoOutput(true);
            con.setConnectTimeout(10000);
            con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEnc);

            InputStream stream = con.getInputStream();
            BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(stream);
            FileOutputStream file = new FileOutputStream("configDown.bin");
            BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(file);
            int i;
            while ((i = in.read()) != -1) {
                out.write(i);
            }
            out.flush();
```

That seemed to work fine! In comparison with the manually (by Browser-Webinterface) downloaded file the generated file have the same length, but after opening both binaries with a hex-editor they were different.

My questions:

1. Any ideas why the hex-codes are different? (Maybe missing connection properties?)
2. There is a copyUrlToFile-Method in the apache.commons package. Is it possible to use it with basic http authentification, as a alternative?
3. Are there other java libs or tools for downloading files from urls?

Comment: Did you check if one was big endian and the other little endian?

Comment: The first 8 Bytes from the files seem to be identical. So i dont think thats an endian problem.

Comment: Just a wild idea, try using Piped streams (here is an example: http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/12982), this will eliminate reading/writing of integers.

Comment: if you want to use GET, don't `setDoOutput` to `true`, because that forces it to use either POST or PUT but i doubt that is the cause.

Comment: Hey gigadot, that was a relict from previous tries... and also the answer! I really can´t explain why POST or PUT have influence on the downloaded file but with "setDoOutput" to "false" it works perfectly and the downloaded config files are identically! Thanks for your help gigadot and also thanks to ShaMan-H for your proposals!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can´t explain why, but the faulty property "setDoOutput" = "true" maybe influenced the content of the downloaded file. Setting the value to "false" solved that issue for me!

Answer (score 1):

IMHO using the (deprecated) Apache Commons HttpClient ( http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/ )is the simplest way to do this. Alternatively you can use the new and (supposedly) improved HttpComponents ( http://hc.apache.org/ ).